# How to Align Buttons side by side in Blackberry

Tags: eclipse, blackberry

I am working on blackberry application, I need to align the buttons side by side, can you please give me a sample code

Thanking you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
final class MyScreen extends MainScreen {
    MyScreen() {
        HorizontalFieldManager hfm = new HorizontalFieldManager();
        hfm.add(new ButtonField("button1"));
        hfm.add(new ButtonField("button2"));
        add(hfm);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you want to add those buttons to HorizontalFieldManager before adding to your Screen.

Answer (score 0):

you can use grid layout manager , refer the following link

http://www.thinkingblackberry.com/archives/116